# Help identify this component: is this a varistor?

Tags: identification, components

Is this a varistor? Can anyone identify this component?

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Description: rubber coated, almost U.S. quarter sized (23.2 mm diameter, 2.2mm thick), dark gray, and the only markings are MCI E-775.

The board it was soldered to is marked R2 and has a 1 MΩ resistor on the backside of the board.

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJAvz.jpg![enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJAvz.jpg!%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiIJJ.jpg)[image][image][image][image]

Comment: Varistor or NTC inrush limiter would be my guess. What did your web search reveal? Can you trace out the schematic around where it sat in your circuit?

Comment: I don't think we're going to determine what this is without seeing the circuit. Trace it out if you can, but at *least* show us photos of the board.

Comment: Any idea of the age of the board? That might help.

Comment: The board is 1998.madrigal labs .I really appreciate all of you for any help

Comment: The pic with the resistor Wich is also blown is the backside of the board

Comment: This is only thing I've been able to find for schematic